# SMTP Disconnecting when running in Docker

Tags: docker, networking, tcp, smtp

I've created a very basic SMTP server in python to receive incoming mail messages. Everything works fine but locally but I'm hitting a problem with the connection disconnecting when trying to send an email to the server when the server is running in docker.

I used wireshark to sniff the traffic and it looks like the smtp server runs on port 25 but there is a random port chosen by the client that is used to communicate back to the client that opened the SMTP request would I need to open this on my docker container? What is the range?

Here is the interaction of a SMTP when I run locally:

[image]

And this is what happens when running in docker:
[image]

It looks like the TCP stream throws a [FIN] right away. Any idea what might be happening or how I can debug?

Steps to replicate:

- Start a local smtp server locally by doing: `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25`
- Test the smtp server by doing `telnet localhost 25`
- Now run the same server in a docker container: `docker run -p 25:25 -it --rm python:3.7-slim python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer`
- Testing using smtp can no longer connect

( Point of Interest: Telnet inside the docker container can connect, so this must be network/port related )

Comment: Yes, TCP clients pick a random port for outgoing connections; you don't need to do anything special in Docker to be able to accept connections or respond to them beyond the usual `docker run -p`.  Can you share your `docker run` command?  Inside the container, what address does your server bind to?

Comment: Here is how you can replicate: locally run `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25` to get a smtp server going. Use `Telnet localhost 25` and you can see it working. Now try: `docker run -p 25:25 -it --rm python:3.7-slim python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25` and now it doesn't work inside docker if you attempt to telnet port 25

Comment: Servers in Docker containers need to be set to bind to 0.0.0.0, otherwise they can't be reached from outside the container at all.  Try changing your last argument to `0.0.0.0:25`.

Comment: That did it, thanks @DavidMaze